# Cant resize div with ng-style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to resize my div when I press the button change. I'm using `ng-style` and this is my code in HTML.

```
<div id="lokacija" ng-style="myStyle">
   <button class="change" ng-show="pokazi" ng-click="myStyle={'height':'{{visina}}'} ;function() ">Change </button> 
 </div>
```

And the controller:

```
    angular.module('Bosk')
.controller('StartCtrl', function($scope){ 
    $scope.visina="99px"; 
      $scope.funkcija = function(){
            var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#lokacija')); 
          var height = element[0].offsetHeight;  
          if(height<100){               
           $scope.visina="400px";
            console.log('if');
          }
          else{
               $scope.visina="99px";
              console.log('else'); 

          }
    } 
})
```

Like u see I want it to when I press first time the button to resize to 400 px and when i press it again I want it to return to 99 px. When I press it the first time it work, but when I want to return it, it doesn't. I must to refresh `ng-style` or?

Comment: `ng-click` has wrong expression, what is `function()` in it.. Though it should be `myStyle={'height': visina }`

Comment: my code works, but i just want to know how to update ng-style. When i press first time the button, it resize. But again when i press its does'nt. that is the problem.